# Intercepting video frames from game

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d

I would like to grab video frames (images) from a game that is launched at PC at the moment.

[XSplit Broadcaster](http://www.xsplit.com/) has such functionality. It somehow listing the processes that are actually video games and allows to grab video frames.

As far as I understand, it can be accomplished by enumerating Direct3D surfaces that are running at the moment and grab the picture from it.

Am I correct? What is the solution for OpenGL games then?

Comment: Have you looked at screen scraping?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [`glReadPixels()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glReadPixels.htm)? I have used it before. It is a little slow though.

Try

```
glReadPixels(0,0,width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`apitrace`](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace) seems able to [capture frames](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Video_Capture) using Ye Olde [`LD_PRELOAD` Tricke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426260/44729).